# Code works on Android studio emulator but not on my android mobile

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-recyclerview

When I use the Android Studio Emulator (Nexus 4 API 23) to emulate an app that I made, it works perfectly. But, when I use my cellphone (Samsung SM-G3502T Android 4.3 API 18) to emulate the same app, it gets stuck at this code bellow:

```
    if(activity instanceof CategoriaListaActivity) {
        boolean isSelected = (categoriaSelectedId == item.getCodigo());
        ((CategoriaViewHolder)holder).getNomeTextView().setTextColor(isSelected ? activity.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark) : activity.getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    }
```

Logcat says:

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Restarter.getActivities
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 2042 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/Restarter;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x006f
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getColor, referenced from method catalog.raulfmiranda.com.catalog.ui.adapter.CategoriaRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 58: Landroid/app/Activity;.getColor (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0058
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getColor, referenced from method catalog.raulfmiranda.com.catalog.ui.adapter.CategoriaRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 58: Landroid/app/Activity;.getColor (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0067
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a7a8c8)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Activity.getColor
                      at catalog.raulfmiranda.com.catalog.ui.adapter.CategoriaRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoriaRecyclerAdapter.java:52)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5825)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: And what documentation says about getCount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a method which is available in API >= 23 ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))), but your mobile only has the deprecated method available ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int))). To solve this, you should use `ContextCompat.getColor(Context, int)` from the support-v4 library.

Comment: Instead of chance color, I decided to chance to bold and italic format. It works now, using: ((CategoriaViewHolder)holder).getNomeTextView().setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);

Answer (score 0):

you are using a call which requires API 23 and above and when testing on emulator which has API 23 its OK but you don't have it on lower APIs

this is the call which requires API 23

```
activity.getColor(int id);
```